# How to keep only the highest duplicated value in data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

**I have the following code:**

```
library(tidyverse)
astronauts %>% 
  group_by(name, nationality, total_hrs_sum) %>% 
  summarise()
```

**The output:**

```
name                                 nationality         total_hrs_sum
<chr>                                <chr>               <dbl>
Acaba, Joseph M.                     U.S.                7272.23        
Acton, Loren Wilbur                  U.S.                190.94     
Adamson, James C.                    U.S.                334.00     
Afanasyev, Viktor Mikhaylovich       U.S.S.R/Russia      13338.55       
Aidyn (Aydyn) Akanovich Aimbetov     Kazakhstan          236.23     
Akers, Thomas D.                     U.S.                814.00     
Akiyama, Toyohiro                    Japan               189.90     
Aksyonov, Vladimir                   U.S.S.R/Russia      284.18     
Al Mansoori, Hazzaa                  UAE                 189.00     
Al-saud, Sultan bin Salman           Saudi Arabia        170.00
```

**My question:**

I would like further filter this data frame such that only 1 name per nationality is provided. That one name per nationality should have the highest value in the total_hrs_sum column. I am most comfortable with dplyr solutions, but am open to other possible solutions as well.

**Sample Data:**

```
structure(list(name = c("Acaba, Joseph M.", "Acton, Loren Wilbur", 
"Adamson, James C.", "Afanasyev, Viktor Mikhaylovich", "Aidyn (Aydyn) Akanovich Aimbetov", 
"Akers, Thomas D.", "Akiyama, Toyohiro", "Aksyonov, Vladimir", 
"Al Mansoori, Hazzaa", "Al-saud, Sultan bin Salman", "Aldrin, Edwin Eugene, Jr.", 
"Aleksandrov, Aleksandr", "Aleksandrov, Aleksandr", "Allen, Andrew M.", 
"Allen, Joseph P.", "Altman, Scott D.", "Anders, William Alison", 
"Anderson, Clayton C.", "Anderson, Michael P.", "André-Deshays, Claudie (Haigneré)", 
"Ansari, Anousheh", "Antonelli, Dominic A.", "Apt, Jerome", "Archambault, Lee J.", 
"Armstrong, Neil A.", "Arnaldo Tamayo Mendez", "Arnold, Richard R., II", 
"Artemyev, Oleg", "Artsebarsky, Anatoly", "Artyukhin, Yuri", 
"Ashby, Jeffrey S.", "Atkov, Oleg", "Aubakirov, Toktar", "Auñón-Chancellor, Serena", 
"Avdeyev, Sergei", "Bagian, James P.", "Baker, Ellen S.", "Baker, Michael A.", 
"Balandin, Aleksandr", "Barratt, Michael R.", "Barry, Daniel T.", 
"Bartoe, John-David Francis", "Baturin, Yuri", "Baudry, Patrick", 
"Bean, Alan Lavern", "Behnken, Robert L.", "Bella, Ivan", "Belyayev, Pavel", 
"Beregovoi, Georgi", "Berezovoy, Anatoly"), nationality = c("U.S.", 
"U.S.", "U.S.", "U.S.S.R/Russia", "Kazakhstan", "U.S.", "Japan", 
"U.S.S.R/Russia", "UAE", "Saudi Arabia", "U.S.", "Bulgaria", 
"U.S.S.R/Russia", "U.S.", "U.S.", "U.S.", "U.S.", "U.S.", "U.S.", 
"France", "U.S.", "U.S.", "U.S.", "U.S.", "U.S.", "Cuba", "U.S.", 
"U.S.S.R/Russia", "U.S.S.R/Russia", "U.S.S.R/Russia", "U.S.", 
"U.S.S.R/Russia", "U.S.S.R/Russia", "U.S.", "U.S.S.R/Russia", 
"U.S.", "U.S.", "U.S.", "U.S.S.R/Russia", "U.S.", "U.S.", "U.S.", 
"U.S.S.R/Russia", "France", "U.S.", "U.S.", "Slovakia", "U.S.S.R/Russia", 
"U.S.S.R/Russia", "U.S.S.R/Russia"), total_hrs_sum = c(7272.23, 
190.94, 334, 13338.55, 236.23, 814, 189.9, 284.18, 189, 170, 
289, 47, 7434.03, 904, 314, 1224, 147, 4046, 593, 614.37, 261.525, 
579, 847, 639.5, 206, 188.71, 307, 8784, 3471.35, 377.5, 664, 
5686.82, 190.2, 4722, 17942.23, 338, 686, 965, 4297.28, 5085, 
734, 190.94, 473.75, 169.63, 1671.75, 708, 190, 26.03, 94.83, 
5073.07)), row.names = c(NA, -50L), groups = structure(list(name = c("Acaba, Joseph M.", 
"Acton, Loren Wilbur", "Adamson, James C.", "Afanasyev, Viktor Mikhaylovich", 
"Aidyn (Aydyn) Akanovich Aimbetov", "Akers, Thomas D.", "Akiyama, Toyohiro", 
"Aksyonov, Vladimir", "Al Mansoori, Hazzaa", "Al-saud, Sultan bin Salman", 
"Aldrin, Edwin Eugene, Jr.", "Aleksandrov, Aleksandr", "Aleksandrov, Aleksandr", 
"Allen, Andrew M.", "Allen, Joseph P.", "Altman, Scott D.", "Anders, William Alison", 
"Anderson, Clayton C.", "Anderson, Michael P.", "André-Deshays, Claudie (Haigneré)", 
"Ansari, Anousheh", "Antonelli, Dominic A.", "Apt, Jerome", "Archambault, Lee J.", 
"Armstrong, Neil A.", "Arnaldo Tamayo Mendez", "Arnold, Richard R., II", 
"Artemyev, Oleg", "Artsebarsky, Anatoly", "Artyukhin, Yuri", 
"Ashby, Jeffrey S.", "Atkov, Oleg", "Aubakirov, Toktar", "Auñón-Chancellor, Serena", 
"Avdeyev, Sergei", "Bagian, James P.", "Baker, Ellen S.", "Baker, Michael A.", 
"Balandin, Aleksandr", "Barratt, Michael R.", "Barry, Daniel T.", 
"Bartoe, John-David Francis", "Baturin, Yuri", "Baudry, Patrick", 
"Bean, Alan Lavern", "Behnken, Robert L.", "Bella, Ivan", "Belyayev, Pavel", 
"Beregovoi, Georgi", "Berezovoy, Anatoly"), nationality = c("U.S.", 
"U.S.", "U.S.", "U.S.S.R/Russia", "Kazakhstan", "U.S.", "Japan", 
"U.S.S.R/Russia", "UAE", "Saudi Arabia", "U.S.", "Bulgaria", 
"U.S.S.R/Russia", "U.S.", "U.S.", "U.S.", "U.S.", "U.S.", "U.S.", 
"France", "U.S.", "U.S.", "U.S.", "U.S.", "U.S.", "Cuba", "U.S.", 
"U.S.S.R/Russia", "U.S.S.R/Russia", "U.S.S.R/Russia", "U.S.", 
"U.S.S.R/Russia", "U.S.S.R/Russia", "U.S.", "U.S.S.R/Russia", 
"U.S.", "U.S.", "U.S.", "U.S.S.R/Russia", "U.S.", "U.S.", "U.S.", 
"U.S.S.R/Russia", "France", "U.S.", "U.S.", "Slovakia", "U.S.S.R/Russia", 
"U.S.S.R/Russia", "U.S.S.R/Russia"), .rows = structure(list(1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
    15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 
    27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 
    39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, 50L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `slice` the first row after grouping by 'nationality' and `arrange`ing the 'total_hrs_sum' in descending order

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%        
    arrange(nationality, desc(total_hrs_sum)) %>%
    group_by(nationality) %>%
    slice(1)
```

---

Or use `top_n`

```
df %>%
    group_by(nationality) %>%
    top_n(n=1, total_hrs_sum)
# A tibble: 10 x 3
# Groups:   nationality [10]
#   name                              nationality    total_hrs_sum
#   <chr>                             <chr>                  <dbl>
# 1 Acaba, Joseph M.                  U.S.                   7272.
# 2 Aidyn (Aydyn) Akanovich Aimbetov  Kazakhstan              236.
# 3 Akiyama, Toyohiro                 Japan                   190.
# 4 Al Mansoori, Hazzaa               UAE                     189 
# 5 Al-saud, Sultan bin Salman        Saudi Arabia            170 
# 6 Aleksandrov, Aleksandr            Bulgaria                 47 
# 7 André-Deshays, Claudie (Haigneré) France                  614.
# 8 Arnaldo Tamayo Mendez             Cuba                    189.
# 9 Avdeyev, Sergei                   U.S.S.R/Russia        17942.
#10 Bella, Ivan                       Slovakia                190
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(nationality) %>% arrange(desc(total_hrs_sum)) %>% filter(!duplicated(nationality))

# A tibble: 10 x 3
# Groups:   nationality [10]
   name                              nationality    total_hrs_sum
   <chr>                             <chr>                  <dbl>
 1 Avdeyev, Sergei                   U.S.S.R/Russia        17942.
 2 Acaba, Joseph M.                  U.S.                   7272.
 3 André-Deshays, Claudie (Haigneré) France                  614.
 4 Aidyn (Aydyn) Akanovich Aimbetov  Kazakhstan              236.
 5 Bella, Ivan                       Slovakia                190 
 6 Akiyama, Toyohiro                 Japan                   190.
 7 Al Mansoori, Hazzaa               UAE                     189 
 8 Arnaldo Tamayo Mendez             Cuba                    189.
 9 Al-saud, Sultan bin Salman        Saudi Arabia            170 
10 Aleksandrov, Aleksandr            Bulgaria                 47
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter like this:

```
astronauts %>%
  group_by(nationality) %>%
  filter(total_hrs_sum == max(total_hrs_sum))
```

See that `max` in a `group_by` data frame would be the max of each group.

This is the output:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 3
# Groups:   nationality [10]
   name                              nationality    total_hrs_sum
   <chr>                             <chr>                  <dbl>
 1 Acaba, Joseph M.                  U.S.                   7272.
 2 Aidyn (Aydyn) Akanovich Aimbetov  Kazakhstan              236.
 3 Akiyama, Toyohiro                 Japan                   190.
 4 Al Mansoori, Hazzaa               UAE                     189 
 5 Al-saud, Sultan bin Salman        Saudi Arabia            170 
 6 Aleksandrov, Aleksandr            Bulgaria                 47 
 7 André-Deshays, Claudie (Haigneré) France                  614.
 8 Arnaldo Tamayo Mendez             Cuba                    189.
 9 Avdeyev, Sergei                   U.S.S.R/Russia        17942.
10 Bella, Ivan                       Slovakia                190
```